# DropzoneJS which one file is?

Tags: detect, dropzone

So, I use DropZoneJS for uploading images for individual products. But i make in database 6 columns for images

```
"image_1" "image_1thumb" "image_2" "image_2thumb" "image_3" "image_3thumb"
```

I make script for uploading images on the host and also to convert image to thumb...

So what i need. How i can detect first, second and third image?
I wanna first image name to write in "image_1" and in "image_1thumb", second in "image_2" and in "image_2thumb" and third one in "image_3" and in "image_3thumb"

Comment: well...is there one dropzone in your page . 1 or 3 .??

Comment: @raja-ji yes, i have one dropzone on my page

Comment: was that of any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dropzone docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-processing) mentions a list of events... one being

```
complete
```

which returns the current file
So for the Dropzone post the processqueue event

```
 this.on("complete", function (file) {
         // this complete will be fired 3 times...in your case        
     });
```

you can manipulate the filename here or you can store then in order and later updated your database